# What are the best free online resources to learn Drunken Kung Fu style?

Tags: self-defense, kung-fu, self-training

Can a weak person learn kung fu? I want to master drunken style. I am fascinated with it. What are the basis of it? and are there any free online resources to learn it?

Comment: You have three questions in there. The first two can easily be answered by a quick Google search. The last one is asking about a list of resources which we do not handle well. There are a few questions about solo learning you should check out.

Answer (score 1):

Drunken kungfu is crazy difficult. It requires significantly higher levels of timing, balance and coordination than most other styles. It may look foolish and easy, but it takes alot of skills to make it look that foolish and easy.

My suggestion is to start with another style first. Once you get the hang of basic stances and your coordination improves, maybe you can talk to your teacher about drunken kungfu. But really, start at the beginning. You don't polevault without being able to run and jump, first.

Comment: what are some resources for free to learn kung fu online?

Answer (score 0):

Learning martial arts online is not a great option. You will need live instruction, which you can then supplement with online instruction. You will also need to live spar, a lot. Hitting pads and bags can only go so far. You need a resisting opponent to determine if your stuff will actually work, and to improve it.

Stop in to your local MMA gym and see what they have to offer. Most will have Boxing, Muay Thai, Dutch Kickboxing, Brazilian Jiu Jitsu, and Wrestling. All great options if you're interested in learning to fight.

Comment: I'll admit that I'm a bit iffy on the answer. On one hand, the first part is good, that you really need to learn with other people. The latter part feels like "But instead of that style, check out my style because it's better."

Comment: @SeanDuggan OP called himself a "weak person". I would hate to see some nonathletic guy throwing YouTube kung fu kicks in their bedroom and think they magically know how to fight. The best way to learn what works in the real world is to just do it. MMA is the closest rule set to real life that you can spar with and not have anyone die. So yes, I avoided the style he brought up, but only because it's extremely dangerous to believe in one's own fighting ability without rigorously testing that ability. If OP is strictly doing it for fun, and not fighting ability/self defense, have at it!